COUNTIFS multiple criteria in Google sheets
Google sheets . . .  . I'm trying to count the number of times a text string is present as well as the quantity associated to it and then have it dynamically update when the table is filtered (other columns exist in real world version). See example below:



Name
Role
Quantity




John
db1
2


Mary
db3
1


John
db2
4


Sarah
db1
3


John
db1
3



=COUNTIFS($I$7:$I$113,"John") only tells me the number of times John exists but not the quantity associated with the Johns and doesn't updated on filtered view.

Welcome to SO! Please share your expected output to clarify the question.

This sounds like a case for a pivot table. Select the data table including the headings(!), use the "Insert" menu and insert a pivot table - you can put it onto the same sheet or on a new one, it doesn't matter.
Then add an entry in "Rows", pick the "Name" field. Next add one "Values" entry, select the "Quantity" field. The sum of quantity per name is automatically added.
To filter values, you have to add extra filters.
Looks something like this:


And if you want to create some formula for regularly filtered values (not in a Pivot table) you have to make use of the SUBTOTAL function.

I've manage to count the quantities for the name and role but I still haven't figured out how to use subtotal for the totals when filtering:
=SUMIFS($J$9:$J$119,$G$9:$G$119,"John",$I$9:$I$119,"db1")
the reason i'd like to figure out the filtered view is there are other columns that i want to filter by to understand the quantities when filtering other columns

Use COUNTIF and SUMIF
To get the number of times the string was present, use COUNTIF. On the other hand, you can use SUMIF to get the sum of the quantity based on the string. You may use the following:
=LET(a,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",UNIQUE(A2:A)),",")),b,byrow(a,lambda(y,COUNTIF(A2:A,y))),c,byrow(a,lambda(x,SUMIF(A2:A,x,C2:C))),HSTACK(a,b,c))

Output

Note: The headers are not part of the formula so you can just manually add them manually.
References:

COUNTIF()
SUMIF()


Please feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above.

If your goal is to list total quantities grouped by name and role then you can use this;
=QUERY(A2:C,"Select A, B, Sum(C) Where A Is Not Null Group By A, B Label A 'NAME', B 'ROLE', Sum(C) 'TOTAL QUANTITY'")

.

.
Or, you can make a pivot table by using the QUERY function below;
=QUERY(A1:C,"Select A, Sum(C) Where A Is Not Null Group By A Pivot B")
.

